# Javascript: why the access to closure variable might be slow

Tags: javascript, performance, functional-programming, closures, interpreter

Recently I've read this [performance guide *Let's make the web faster*](http://code.google.com/intl/en/speed/articles/optimizing-javascript.html) and was puzzled by "Avoiding pitfalls with closures" recommendations (as if these advices were given for CommonLisp users where variable scoping is dynamic):

> ```
> var a = 'a';
> function createFunctionWithClosure() {
>   var b = 'b';
>   return function () {
>     var c = 'c';
>     a;
>     b;
>     c;
>   };
> }
>
> var f = createFunctionWithClosure();
> f();
> ```
>
> **when `f` is invoked, referencing `a` is slower than referencing `b`, which is slower than referencing `c`.**

It's quite evident that referencing local variable *c* is faster than *b*, but if the iterpreter is written properly (without dynamic scoping - something like chained hashtable lookup..) the speed difference should be only marginal. Or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right. Modern JS engines will optimize the `scope chain lookup` and the `prototype chain lookup` like a lot. Means, AFAIK the engine trys to hold some sort of hash-table with access nodes underneath.

This only works if there is no `eval()` (explicity or implicitly, e.g. `setTimeout`) or a `try-catch` clause or `a with statement` invoked. Because of such constructs, the interpretator can't be sure about how to access data and it needs to "fallback" into a classical `scope chain lookup` which really means, it has to crawl through all parent context `variable / activation objects` and try to resolve the searched variable name.
This process of, of course, will take more time for objects/names which are located "far away" from where the lookup processed was started. That in turn means, that accessing data on the `global object` will always be the slowest.

In your snippet, the lookup process for `a` would go like

```
anonymous function -> Execution Context -> Activation Object (not found)
anonymous function -> Execution Context -> [[ Scope ]] 
    - createFunctionWithClosure
    - global scope
createFunctionWithClosure -> Activation Object (not found)
global scope -> Variable Object (found)
```

---

<sup>The described lookup procedure is for ECMAscript Edition 262 3rd edition. ECMAscript edition 5 has some fundamental changes there.</sup>

Comment: For longevity (and my curiosity) can you describe how it is changing in v5?

Comment: So if I would do `var d = eval("this");` inside the anonymous function, the scope chain lookup will crawl through all contexts to get the reference of `a`? Or will it just do that to assign `this` to `d`?

Comment: @headacheCoder: that is very possible if that code runs in some kind of "old'ish" browser. However, you actually should never do such a terrible statement anyway :) Cutting-edge browser will even be able to still optimize things using `eval`, might even depent on `strict mode`. But those browsers follow the ES5 spec anyway.