# Variable scopes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables, scope

Short question:

Let's say we have jQuery included. Will this function execute faster ...

```
var example1 = (function($, jQuery) {
    return function() {
        // do something
    }
})()
```

... than the following one:

```
var example2 = (function() {
    return function() {
        // do something
    }
})()
```

?

In the first one the jQuery object will be `undefined`, in the second one it will be inherited. So the second one should be more expensive?

What is the best way to improve speed and get rid of inherited variables that decreases performance?

jsPerf test: http://jsperf.com/objinheritance

Comment: This might answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248963/javascript-why-the-access-to-closure-variable-might-be-slow

Comment: In the second one it will not be inherited, will it?  It will just be global.  Just like in the first one.  It is only undefined if you access it locally, you still have window.$ and window.jQuery.

Comment: Quote: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil". Go ahead and learn about scopes in JS, very good - but DO NOT optimize for the sake of optimization. This particular issue is relevant only when a piece of code is executed thousands of times (at once). Keyword to google: "scope-chain". Computer (CPU) time is MUCH cheaper than developer time!!!

Comment: I don't think global variables decrease performance, nor do I think eclipsing them with undefined local variables will increase it.  Nor do I think it worth writing confusing/ugly code for a performance hit that may not hold true over time.  Just write normal, clean code and let the JavaScript engine developers worry about the under-the-hood performance.

Comment: @Mörre: +1, and optimization of this nature in JavaScript will always be premature.

Comment: It's just about understanding it. I don't want to set everything to `undefined` just to increase the performance. But it's quite interesting how the stuff works.

Comment: The jsperf test crashes firefox and opera :(

Comment: It might be good to note that this has nothing to do with inheritance (`objinheritance`?). The 1st snippet is an example of lexical closures and variable shadowing -- the arguments *over-shadow* the global variables defined by jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As ECMAScript defines, **reference resolution** is a inner-to-outer lookup process, so in the first example, the `$` variable is **1 step** from your code, and in the second example, while `$` resides in global scope, it is at least **2 steps** away, which cause extra lookup overhead.

However, in real world, modern javascript engines (such as V8) doesn't implement reference resolution the exactly same way which ECMAScript states, they have an approach to **flattern** the scope chain, in other words, for most code, all variables can be referenced in **a single step**, no **lookup overhead** at all.

Conslusion: they are really same to each other.

PS: as well as the **scope chain**, javascript engines have quite the same optimization on **prototype chain**, so there is also no need to worry about a property lookup overhead.